# Age intervals as row statistics with SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create this summary statistic table, counting the number of individuals in each category

```
Agegroup   |    All    |    Female   |    Male
------------------------------------------------
All        |  560594   |    34324    |   234244
< 20       |   4324    |     545     |    3456
20 - 30    |  76766    |     3424    |   32428
30 - 40    |  36766    |     764     |   82427
40 - 50    |  46766    |     4324    |   72422
50 - 60    |  66766    |     3424    |   52424
> 60       |  76766    |    43424    |   12423
```

from this table

```
PersonID  |   Age   |  Sex   
----------------------------
  A      |    43    |   F
  B      |    22    |   F
  C      |    65    |   M
  D      |    33    |   F
  E      |    28    |   M
```

Is this even possible "in one go" with SQL? I experimented with this, but it's not really coming together..

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Age < 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Under 20],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [20-30],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 30 AND 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [30-40]
FROM Persons
```

Comment: What are you using mssql, oracel, mysql?

Comment: @wije - In what agegroup would you expect someone who is 30? `20-30`,  `30-40` or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the below is the simplest way to achieve this, and also get the row back even if there are no people within that age range. Also since `Sex` only has 2 possible values you can use `NULLIF` instead of the case expression.

```
SELECT  [Agegroup] = Name,
        [All] = COUNT(Person.PersonID),
        [Female] = COUNT(NULLIF(Person.Sex, 'M')),
        [Male] = COUNT(NULLIF(Person.Sex, 'F'))
FROM    (VALUES 
            (0, 1000, 'All'),
            (0, 20, '< 20'),
            (20, 30, '20 - 30'),
            (30, 40, '30 - 40'),
            (40, 50, '40 - 40'),
            (50, 60, '50 - 40'),
            (60, 1000, '> 60')
        ) AgeRange (MinValue, MaxValue, Name)
        LEFT JOIN Person
            ON Person.Age >= AgeRange.MinValue
            AND Person.Age < AgeRange.Maxvalue
GROUP BY AgeRange.Name, AgeRange.MinValue, AgeRange.Maxvalue
ORDER BY AgeRange.MinValue, AgeRange.MaxValue DESC
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6af11/3)**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(PersonID VARCHAR(5), Age INT,Sex VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
    ('A',43,'F'),
    ('B',22 ,'F'),
    ('C ',65,'M'),
    ('D',33,'F'),
    ('E',28,'M')
```

SQL

```
SELECT
    'All' AS Agegroup,
    COUNT(*) AS [All],
    SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.Sex='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.Sex='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male
FROM
    @T AS tbl
UNION ALL   
SELECT
    tbl.Agegroup,
    COUNT(*) AS [All],
    SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.Sex='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.Sex='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (
            CASE 
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 0 and 20
            THEN '< 20'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 20 and 30
            THEN '20 - 30'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 30 and 40
            THEN '30 - 40'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 40 and 50
            THEN '40 - 50'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 50 and 60
            THEN '50 - 60'
            WHEN Age> 60
            THEN '> 60'
            END
        ) AS Agegroup,
        t.Age,
        t.Sex
    FROM
        @T AS t
) AS tbl
GROUP BY
    tbl.Agegroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best pattern would be to create an age range table (or virtual table as in the example below) and join to it, then pivot the results to get your results into a columnar form.

```
select range as AgeGroup, m as Male, F as Female, m+f as [all]
from
(  
    select PersonID, range, sex  
    from
    (
        select 'all' as range, 0 as minval, 200 as maxval
        union select '<20',0,19
        union select '20-29',20,29
        -- etc....
    ) ranges
        left join
    yourtable t
        on t.age between minval and maxval
) src
pivot
    (count(personid) for sex in ([m],[f])) p
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
;with Age_range as(
select '<20' as age union all
select '20 - 30' as age union all
select '30 - 40' as age union all
select '40 - 50' as age union all
select '50 - 60' as age union all
select '>60' as age  
),
cte as(
select [Sex],
sum(case when [Age]<20 then 1 else 0 end) as '<20' ,
sum(case when [Age]between 20 and 29 then 1 else 0 end) as '20 - 30',
sum(case when [Age]between 30 and 39 then 1 else 0 end) as '30 - 40',
sum(case when [Age]between 40 and 49 then 1 else 0 end) as '40 - 50',
sum(case when [Age]between 50 and 59 then 1 else 0 end) as '50 - 60',
sum(case when [Age]>=60 then 1 else 0 end) as '>60' 
 from Persons
 group by [Sex]),
 cte1 as(select Sex,'<20'  as cnt from cte where [<20]>0 union all
 select Sex,'20 - 30'  as cnt from cte where [20 - 30]>0 union all
 select Sex,'30 - 40'  as cnt from cte where [30 - 40]>0 union all
 select Sex,'40 - 50'  as cnt from cte where [40 - 50]>0 union all
 select Sex,'50 - 60'  as cnt from cte where [50 - 60]>0 union all
 select Sex,'>60'  as cnt from cte where [>60]>0)
 select A.age,
        COUNT(case when sex in ('M','F') then 1 end) as [All],
        COUNT(case when sex='F' then 1 end) as Female,
        COUNT(case when sex='M' then 1 end) as Male
  from Age_range A left join cte1 C
  on A.age=C.cnt
  group by A.age
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89f29/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  'All' as [Age Group]
.       count(*) as [All],
,       sum(case Sex when 'F' then 1 end) as Female
,       sum(case Sex when 'M' then 1 end) as Male
from    Persons
union all
select  '< 20' as [Age Group]
.       count(*) as [All],
,       sum(case Sex when 'F' then 1 end) as Female
,       sum(case Sex when 'M' then 1 end) as Male
from    Persons
where   Age < 20
union all
select  '20 - 30' as [Age Group]
.       count(*) as [All],
,       sum(case Sex when 'F' then 1 end) as Female
,       sum(case Sex when 'M' then 1 end) as Male
from    Persons
where   20 <= Age and Age < 30
union all
...
```